# How do I retrieve the returned value when using the pop() method in Python?

Tags: python, list, data-structures

I'm completing an exercise that has given me a list and requires me to remove an element at an index and then insert that element into another position in the list. I've researched how the `.pop()` method works, and python.org mentions that it returns the indexed value. Where is this value stored? How can I retrieve it?

Comment: It is returned by the `pop` method, what do you mean where is it stored? It's stored anywhere you like, assigned to a variable, added to a data structure etc...

Comment: When I was reading the definition on the website is says that The value is returned, but where to since that specific element is not stored in a variable. How can I access that element that was removed so that I can insert it into another position in the given list.

Comment: It's the same as any other function... `def foo(): return 42`, if you just do `foo()` well, you never stored it anywhere, so you cannot access the return value. You'd have *to do this yourself*, e.g. `value = foo()` or suppose you have a list, `mylist.append(foo())`... This is always how return values work. They don't get magically stored anywhere or assigned to arbitrary variables for you.

Comment: This makes sense I get it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve as below:

```
list_example = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] # List example
removed = list_example.pop(3) # remove by index 
list_example.insert(2, removed) # Adding the element removed in the position required
```

The result would be:

```
[1, 2, 4, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

The value is returned by the `.pop()` method. If you want the value, you could do (where `index` is the index of the item you want to remove):

```py
index = 3
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
value = lst.pop(index)
```

and if you wanted to insert it back into the list at a different location, you could do:

```py
new_index = 1
old_index = 3
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
lst.insert(new_index, lst.pop(old_index))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store it into a variable like:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
last_value_popped = array.pop(-1)

print(array)
print(last_value_popped)
```

**output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
5
```

Comment: Are you serious ? Why did you `pop` the last item passing a value if  `pop` remove the last item by default.

Comment: Because you could also pop(1) or (2), or (n). But (-1) is just the default option, i think this is useful to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the value returned by pop by doing `popped=li.pop()` where `li` is the list and the popped value is stored in `popped`.
By default this pops the last item in the list.
To pop value at specific index do `li.pop(<index>)`.
To insert value at specific index do `li.insert(<index>,<value>)`.
**Example:**

```
li=[1, 2, 3, 4]
val1=li.pop() #val1 = 4
val2=li.pop(1) #val2 = 2
li.insert(0,val1) #li = [4, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

### To Insert A Particular Element At A Particular Index Try This-

```
mylist = ['ele1', 'ele2', 'ele3']
# To Remove An `ele` at a certain index or by name
INDEX = 0  # Removes 'ele1'
mylist.pop(INDEX)
# By Name
ele = 'ele2'
mylist.remove(ele)

# To Insert In a list

mylist.insert('ele4 BRAND NEW!', -1)  # This Means Insert 'ele4 BRAND NEW' indexed at the very last of the list '-1' stands for the last ele of the list
```

**Hope So This Helped!**

#### Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [1,2,32,4,454,2]
elem = arr.pop(3) // 3 is the index of the list
print(elem)       // this will print 4
```

Answer (score 0):

pop() removes last entered element from a list. You can  retrieve that element using:

val = list_name.pop() #val will store your popped element.

But as your question is concerned to remove an element at particular location and putting into some other location,try this out. Suppose you have list:
x = [12,23,433,32,343] #remove element from 2nd positon and place it in last position
#use this
x[-1] = x.pop(1) #specifing location in pop() removes element from particular index

hope this works!!